# Send request to websocket server using JSON data

Tags: c#, json, websocket, json.net, obs

Basically, I have OBS running on a computer and I need to interact with it through a second computer.
I am using an [OBS-WebSocket](https://github.com/Palakis/obs-websocket) plugin which is creating a websocket server on OBS to send remote commands.

My goal is to set visible / invisible a source on OBS whenever I press a key on the second (remote) computer.
I have no issue with that key press part. My issue is that I have no idea how to correctly send a request/command to the websocket plugin (it requires JSON format as this is how data is formatted).

**Main code (C#)**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.1:1122"))
        {

            ws.Connect();
            ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
                Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
            ws.Send("REPLACE WITH JSON REQUEST DATA");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
```

**Down below is an example of data received from the websocket whenever I turn on or off a source in OBS.**

You can clearly see that the 'visibility' is either false or true.

***This *'item-visible'* is the setting I need to mess with to tell OBS to hide or show the source.***

**↓ Source is visible in OBS ↓**

```
{
"item-id": 10,
"item-name": "map",
"item-visible": true,
"scene-name": "ONHOLD",
"update-type": "SceneItemVisibilityChanged"
}
```

**↓ Source is hidden in OBS ↓**

```
{
"item-id": 10,
"item-name": "map",
"item-visible": false,
"scene-name": "ONHOLD",
"update-type": "SceneItemVisibilityChanged"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see [example test usages](https://github.com/Palakis/obs-websocket-dotnet/blob/master/obs-websocket-dotnet/OBSWebsocket.cs) in the official Github repo.

If you look there, you'd see that that `e.Data` should be parsed. Then, you can assign it as needed, for example:

```
public string SetIsVisible(MessageEventArgs e, bool isVisible)
{
    JObject body = JObject.Parse(e.Data);
    body["item-visible"] = isVisible;
    return body.ToString();
}
```

... and then just send the returned string into your websocket:

```
ws.Send(SetIsVisible(e, isVisible)); // isVisible is boolean you should assign
```

P.S. If you'd like to work with a static-type DTO, simply generate one (e.g. [here](https://app.quicktype.io/?l=csharp)):

```
public partial class OBSSource
{
    [JsonProperty("item-id")]
    public long ItemId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("item-name")]
    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("item-visible")]
    public bool ItemVisible { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("scene-name")]
    public string SceneName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("update-type")]
    public string UpdateType { get; set; }
}
```

... and then:

```
public string SetIsVisible(MessageEventArgs e, bool isVisible)
{
    OBSSource obsSource = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OBSSource>(e.Data);
    obsSource.ItemVisible = isVisible;
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obsSource);
}
```

... and then send it serialized into the websocket as above.